# How to prevent server crash while flying with Elytra?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friend and I recently just acquired a set of Elytra for the both of us! Naturally, we've been exploring like crazy. However, the server we play on tends to crash if we fly for too long in any given direction. The crash logs say things like "player moved to quickly", and "cannot keep up". I'm fairly certain we're just loading chunks too fast for the server to handle.

My question is, what can we do clientside and serverside to try and prevent this?

For reference, we're running 1.12 on an Ubuntu server. Also, when we fly we turn our render distance up to 20 to see farther. Both times this has happened, only one of us we're flying, the other was staying near the spawn area.

**Server Specs:**

- 24gb RAM, with 4gb of it allocated to the mc server
- 2x 2.4 ghz Intel Xeon 5500, 6 cores, and hyperthreading
- 250gb SSD runs OS

Comment: Against "player moved too fast", try `/gamerule disableElytraMovementCheck` (warning, this could allow cheaters to teleport around in your world). For the crash, I'm not really sure, your specs look at least ok, if not very good (I'm not am expert). But you can of course always try to reduce the server load by reducing its render distance in `server.properties`. Die this help? Then I'll post it as an answer. If not, I need more details, like the full game log for example.

Comment: @Fabian. We already allow teleporting anyways so that wouldn't be an issue :p. I will try that command when I have time later today, and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Have you turned up the Max Render Distance in the server config as well? I believe that turning your client's render distance up past the value in the config won't really make any difference. Also, does it only crash when loading new chunks, or just from moving too fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep that render distance there is one simple solution: Allocate more RAM. 20 Chunks of of render distance while flying with an Elytra will knock out your memory, especially when there are chunks being generated and not just loaded. You don't have to max it out so the CPU won't fry.

You can simply use these in the server's startup parameters:

```
-Xms[minValue] -Xmx[maxValue]
```

The server will then initially use the min value of RAM and may be use it up to the max value. You can choose the unit size, such as Mega- (e.g. `4048M`) or Gigabytes (e.g. `4G`). For example:

```
- Xms4048M -Xmx16192M
```

These would for example allocate at least 4GB of RAM and the server is allowed to use up to 16 GB. Using more RAM increases the CPU load, so you have to watch how far you can go with that.

Answer (score 2):

I've poked around a bit, and I think I have a few answers.
You can either install a plugin that periodically unloads chunks (Such as [Clearlag](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/clearlagg)) so that the server  doesn't become overwhelmed with the amount of chunks loaded.
**OR** you can lower the MaxRenderDistance in the server config to reduce the number of chunks loaded.