# Server crashes after "player moved too quickly"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem on my server, when for example someone flies with the Elitres wings or many players are running discovering new chunks in different places on the map, the following warning appears on the server:

"player moved too quickly"

But when it happens with several players, the server crashes, I do not know if it is a server problem, or if it is some bad configuration of the server files, since an old admin said that he had modified them to go better, but I do not know. ...

Comment: The server dealing with many new chunks simultaneously may simply exceed its allocated resources. Can you watch actual memory consumption, messages emitted on the unexpected shutdown, or compare configured limits to hard limitations of the machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent server crash while flying with Elytra?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318866/how-to-prevent-server-crash-while-flying-with-elytra)

Comment: This can be dealt with, if you're using Spigot/Paper. Or simply explore the map yourself when the server is empty, so others don't cause such an impact when people are online.

Comment: Server in OMGSERV with Intel Xeon Processors E5-2670 (2.6 / 3.3GHz), RAM UNLIMITED and SSD Storage UNILIMTED